# How can I optimize the performance of mysql vm in a nginx load balancer group?

Tags: ubuntu, nginx, load-balancing, high-availability, multiple-instances

I built a mysql HA group with 3 ubuntu vms. One is load balancer and the other two are mysql vms. Each mysql vm is with 8 mysql instances which corresponding with 8 ports   and there are 8 ports on load balancer which corresponding with the ones in mysql vms. The two mysql vms are master-master replication to each other.
But when I tested the performance of mysql with sysbench, the performance is quite poor in load balancer while it is ok if I tested it in one of the mysql vm.

I used the command

`sysbench --test=oltp --mysql-host=192.168.1.11 --mysql-port=3307 --mysql-user=xxx --mysql-password=xxx --mysql-db=test1 --num-threads=32 --max-time=1800 --max-requests=0 --oltp-table-size=10000000 run>> /var/tmp/mysql3307.txt`

in load balancer and get the result

```
OLTP test statistics:
queries performed:
    read:                            3522974
    write:                           1258168
    other:                           503270
    total:                           5284412
transactions:                        251629 (139.78 per sec.)
deadlocks:                           12     (0.01 per sec.)
read/write requests:                 4781142 (2655.95 per sec.)
other operations:                    503270 (279.57 per sec.)

Test execution summary:
total time:                          1800.1653s
total number of events:              251629
total time taken by event execution: 57596.9970
per-request statistics:
     min:                                 42.53ms
     avg:                                228.90ms
     max:                               3086.55ms
     approx.  95 percentile:             407.86ms

Threads fairness:
events (avg/stddev):           7863.4062/381.89
execution time (avg/stddev):   1799.9062/0.05
```

But when I tested in one mysql vm

`sysbench --test=oltp --mysql-host=127.0.0.1 --mysql-port=3307 --mysql-user=xxx --mysql-password=xxx --mysql-db=test1 --num-threads=32 --max-time=1800 --max-requests=0 --oltp-table-size=10000000 run>> /var/tmp/mysql3307.txt`

the result is

```
OLTP test statistics:
queries performed:
    read:                            140070
    write:                           50010
    other:                           20005
    total:                           210085
transactions:                        10000  (317.15 per sec.)
deadlocks:                           5      (0.16 per sec.)
read/write requests:                 190080 (6028.38 per sec.)
other operations:                    20005  (634.46 per sec.)

Test execution summary:
total time:                          31.5308s
total number of events:              10000
total time taken by event execution: 1007.3012
per-request statistics:
     min:                                 13.73ms
     avg:                                100.73ms
     max:                                589.49ms
     approx.  95 percentile:             184.95ms

Threads fairness:
events (avg/stddev):           312.5000/6.02
execution time (avg/stddev):   31.4782/0.04
```

The load-balance configuration of the nginx in load balancer is

```
stream {
server {
   listen 3307;
   proxy_pass db3307;
}
upstream db3307 {
   server 192.168.1.11:3307 weight=1;
   server 192.168.1.12:3307 weight=1;
}
server {
   listen 3308;
   proxy_pass db3308;
}
upstream db3308 {
   server 192.168.1.11:3308 weight=1;
   server 192.168.1.12:3308 weight=1;
}
//... to port 3314
}
```

I think the cause of the poor performance is the nginx load balance, but I don't know how to optimize it. Is there any one can help me? Thank you.